# Combining two csv files with one common element and sort without pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have two csv files that look like

goals.csv

```
CLUB, GOALS FOR, GOALS AGAINST
liverpool, 45, 17
chelsea, 37, 23
arsenal, 39, 26
```

and cards.csv

```
CLUB, YELLOW, RED
liverpool, 14, 1
chelsea, 12, 2
arsenal, 16, 4
```

I'm trying to combine the two files and then sort by a new column called *GOALS RATIO* where the ratio is *GOALS FOR / GOALS AGAINST*

to look like

```
CLUB, GOALS FOR, GOALS AGAINST, YELLOW, RED, RATIO
liverpool, 45, 17, 14, 1, X
chelsea, 37, 23, 12, 2, X
arsenal, 39, 26, 16, 4, X
```

My current code is

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict


def facebook_dino():
    goals =  "goal.csv"
    cards = "cards.csv"

    new_dict = defaultdict()

    with open(goals) as csv1:
        goals_data = csv.DictReader(csv1)

    with open(cards) as csv2:
        cards_data = csv.DictReader(csv2)
```

But can't find a way to combine the two CSVs based on the *NAME* keyword argument. Is this possible with or without pandas?

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev i thought i wasn't able to install pandas but now can, updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the rows in matching order of names.

This is the output:

```
    CLUB,GOALS FOR,GOALS AGAINST,YELLOW,RED,RATIO
    liverpool,45,17,14,1,2.65
    chelsea,37,23,12,2,1.61
    arsenal,39,26,16,4,1.5
```

This is the code

```
    import csv
    import os

    goals_csv = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'goals.csv')
    cards_csv = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'cards.csv')
    output = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'combined.csv')
    with open(goals_csv) as goals, open(cards_csv) as cards, open(output, 'w') as output:
        goal_rows = csv.DictReader(goals)
        card_rows = csv.DictReader(cards)
        headers = "CLUB,GOALS FOR,GOALS AGAINST,YELLOW,RED,RATIO".split(",")
        output_csv = csv.DictWriter(output, headers)
        output_csv.writeheader()
        while True:
            goal_row = next(goal_rows, None)
            if goal_row is None:
                break
            card_row = next(card_rows, None)
            goal_row.update(card_row)
            goals_against = float(goal_row['GOALS AGAINST'])
            goals_for = float(goal_row['GOALS FOR'])
            goal_row['RATIO'] = 0 if goals_against == 0 else round(goals_for / goals_against, 2)
            output_csv.writerow(goal_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is using pandas library :

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('goal.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('cards.csv')
for col in df2.columns:
    df1[col] = df2[col]
df1['RATIO'] = df1[' GOALS FOR']/df1[' GOALS AGAINST']
print(df1)
```

**Output** :

```
        CLUB   GOALS FOR   GOALS AGAINST   YELLOW   RED     RATIO
0  liverpool          45              17       14     1  2.647059
1    chelsea          37              23       12     2  1.608696
2    arsenal          39              26       16     4  1.500000
```